# PHP sanitization question

Tags: php

I was wondering how would you sanitize the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_POST['email'] and $url code in the code snippets below using PHP.

I'm using PHP Version 5.2.14

Code Snippets.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
</form>

$email = $_POST['email']; //Grabs the email address

$page_url = $url; //Grabs the pages url address.
```

Comment: you may want to see this page: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: You can just omit the `action` attribute entirely in your example.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams why shouldn;t it be filtered to?

Comment: @redEYE `<form method="post">` will post the form to the same page you are on, which is what you are doing when setting `action` to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: Sanitize _against what exactly_? HTML injection, SQL injection, something else?

Answer (score 2):

Use [filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) functions.

```
 // url
 filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)
 // email
 filter_var('me@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Except in some very particular cases you should never 'sanitize' input - only ever validate it. (Except in the very particular cases) the only time you change the representation of data is where it leaves your PHP - and the method should be appropriate to where the data is going (e.g. htmlentities(), urlencode(), mysql_real_escape_string()....).

(the filter functions referenced in other posts validate input - they don't change its representation)